# How can I locate to this image by using selenium (python script)?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I would like to know how to use selenium to locate to this img location by using selenium by using python script.
I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='welcome-tooltip-dialog']/img[1]").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("tooltip-dialog-list")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src*='images/close-button.png']")
```

But all of them are not working properly.

Comment: Post the website URL in a Edit or in the comment and I'll take a look.

Comment: URL link: https://conversation-demo.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is inside `<iframe>` tag, you need to switch to it first

```
# switch to the iframe
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# close the tooltip
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#welcome-tooltip-dialog > .close').click()

# switch back
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='welcome-tooltip-dialog']/img[1]")
```

This is the actual src attribute if you need to use the actual image for something:

```
src = img.get_attribute('src')
```

If you are clicking for the sake of clicking:

```
img.click()
```

Comment: Not useful since he's trying to .click (using the selenium method) on the element, he doesn't want to extract the Img url or path. 
Nothing he hasn't done.. You've just put it in a variable but it doesn't exectue that's his problem and unless he puts a url I can't really troubleshoot.